# Unable to read input file : Pig store to MYSQL using DBStorage

Tags: mysql, apache-pig

I am trying to store data to MySQL using DBStorage in pig script.
when I run the the script ,I am getting error unable to read the input file.
Whereas when I try to dump to store the same data file its working fine.
Sample pigscript :

```
%default DATABASE_HOST 'localhost';
%default DATABASE_NAME 'Test';
%default DATABASE_USER 'username';
%default DATABASE_PASS 'password';
%default DATABASE_DRIVER 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver';
%default DATABASE_TYPE 'mysql';



A = LOAD '/tmp/TestDivya/Pig/PigSQLTest.txt' using PigStorage() as (name: chararray);
STORE A into 'test' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage('$DATABASE_DRIVER', 'jdbc:$DATABASE_TYPE://$DATABASE_HOST/$DATABASE_NAME',  '$DATABASE_USER', '$DATABASE_PASS', 'INSERT INTO Test(name) VALUES (?)');

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485      0.15.0.2.3.4.0-3485     hdfs    2016-01-21 01:34:552016-01-21 01:35:07      UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1453263223178_0042  A       MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed!    hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hdfs/test,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/tmp/TestDivya/Pig/PigSQLTest.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ap-xxxxxx-1.compute.internal:8020/user/hdfs/test"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1453263223178_0042
```

My cluster is set up on EC2 having Hortonworks HDP 2.3.4 and using the HDP MYSQL database for storing the pig output.

Would really appreciate the pointers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .
Have to add mysql connector as additional jars in pig.properties file.
and it worked .
adding it in the pig console ,didn't helped.

Thanks